# How to make a basic thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class `main.cpp`, as well as `MyClass.cpp`.

In `main.cpp`, I have a lot of code. At the top though, I create a `MyClass` object and then I'd like to start a thread that is in `MyClass`. I'd like it to call a function `Run()` and have the function run at the same time that the rest of the functions in `main.cpp` run.

What is the easiest way to do this in C++. I've never done threading in C++, however I have done so in Java.

I'd like to avoid using external packages and such if possible.

Comment: Are you using a version of C++ that includes native multi-threading? If not, which platform are you targeting? (My strong advice to you would be to use [Boost](http://boost.org). Yes, it's an external package, but it's portable, well-made, and leads to better code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard C++:

```
#include <future>

int main() {
    MyClass mc;
    auto future = std::async(MyClass::Run,&mc);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way for you to go is to use [boost thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/) library.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

...

int main()
{
  ...
  MyClass mc;
  boost::thread bt(boost::bind(MyClass::Run, &mc));
  ...
  bt.join();
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language itself doesn't have any notion of threads*.  You can certainly write multithreaded programs in C++, but it will involve using a platform-specific thread library.  For example, you can use the "pthreads" library on Linux systems.  What is your target platform?

*The extensions added in the new C++11 spec add standardized support for threads, but many compilers and standard libraries do not yet implement this version of the standard.